# Импорт переменной из другого .py

Tags: python, импорт

при запуске пишет:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Projects\NP4\Folder1\src\main.py", line 2, in from other_sites
    import site1
ImportError: cannot import name 'site1' from 'other_sites' (d:\Projects\NP4\Folder1\src\other_sites.py)
```

Не могу понять почему код не видит переменную в другом файле.
`main.py` и `other_sites.py` находятся в одной директории.

`main.py`:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Button
from other_sites import site1
import webbrowser

window = Tk()
window.title("W")
window.geometry("267x1040+{:d}+0".format(window.winfo_screenwidth()-267))  # Установка размеров и положения окна
window.overrideredirect(1)

def open_site(site_url):
    if site_url:
        webbrowser.open(site_url)

frame = Frame(window)
frame.pack()

button1 = Button(frame, text="STOP", width=25, height=3, command=window.destroy)
button1.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, padx=5, pady=5)

button2 = Button(frame, text="Button 1", width=9, height=3, command=lambda: open_site(site1))
button2.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=35)

window.mainloop()
```

`other_sites.py`:

```
site1 = "https://learn-anything.xyz/"
site2 = "https://learn-anything.xyz/"
site3 = "https://learn-anything.xyz/"
site4 = "https://learn-anything.xyz/"
site5 = "https://learn-anything.xyz/"
site6 = ""
site7 = ""
site8 = ""
site9 = ""
site10 = ""
site11 = ""
site12 = ""
site13 = ""
site14 = ""
site15 = ""
site16 = ""
site17 = ""
site18 = ""
site19 = ""
site20 = ""
site21 = ""
```

Comment: ваш код работает нормально (по крайней мере, импорты). проверьте сохранили ли вы файлы, действительно ли они лежат в одной директории, проверьте имена файлов

Answer (score 0):

Скрипту нужно понимать, что файл находится в той же директории. Поэтому вместо from `other_sites import site1` используй `from .other_sites import site1` (точка перед именем файла).

Скрипт будет выглядеть так:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Button
from .other_sites import site1
import webbrowser

window = Tk()
window.title("W")
window.geometry("267x1040+{:d}+0".format(window.winfo_screenwidth()-267))  # Установка размеров и положения окна
window.overrideredirect(1)

def open_site(site_url):
    if site_url:
        webbrowser.open(site_url)

frame = Frame(window)
frame.pack()

button1 = Button(frame, text="STOP", width=25, height=3, command=window.destroy)
button1.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, padx=5, pady=5)

button2 = Button(frame, text="Button 1", width=9, height=3, command=lambda: open_site(site1))
button2.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=35)

window.mainloop()
```

Также в папке должен быть файл `__init__.py`, чтобы папка воспринималась как пакет. Файл может быть пустым.

Comment: `from .other_sites import site1` - это не будет работать, если текущая папка не запущена как пакет.

Comment: проблема не в этом, я буквально скопировал код из вопроса и запустил его у себя на машине. всё работает.

Answer (score 0):

Благодарю за помощь, но проблема оказалось максимально банальной.
При создании файла other_sites.py и внесении в него переменных я просто-напросто забыл сохранить файл.
Мне почему-то казалось что при завершении работы VScode сам сохраняет файл, но увы это не так.
Поэтому импорт видел файл other_sites.py но не видел в нем переменных.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]